# .htaccess mod_rewrite not catching entire URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Whatever I add to the URL mod_rewrite catches it and puts in it the GET variable url and redirects the user in the background to my index.php page.

Example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/members/profile
```

In my index.php page if I then output the url parameter to the screen I get

```
members/profile
```

That is what I want but the problem is when I add something like this to the URL:

```
members/profile##
```

OR

```
members/profile...
```

and probably loads of other special characters mod_rewrite only seems to catch the:

```
members/profile
```

leaving out the characters at the end for some reason.

I don't want that as I need catch every single chacter in the URL. Does anyone know why it is not catching the whole URL? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very hard to understand. PLease try to edit it and make things more clear: what is the issue you want to solve? what exactly is not working? What do yo mean by "echo out to screen"? waht do you mean by "I need to be able to see"?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code with a `.htaccess` file containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

and this php script called `index.php`:

```
<?php
echo '$_GET[\'url\'] = "' . $_GET['url'] . '"';
?>
```

Indeed, it didn't work. But nothing worked, not even the things you described that did. So why would that be case? Well, Apache doesn't pass `GET` parameters to the script unless you add a flag: [QSA](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA). So your code will work if you change your `.htaccess` file to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

One issue you had was that hashtags weren't passes to the PHP script. Unfortunately, that is something you can't solve. The reason for this is that every character starting at the first hash isn't passed to the webserver by the browser. So you will never be able to get those characters, unless you resort to some fancy JavaScript.